# re.findall() where I want all unique instances of the regex on the page

Tags: python, regex, findall

As the title suggests, I want to run code like this (top_url_list is just a list of urls I'm looping through to find instances of these filename conventions that I'm looking for with regex:

```
    name_files = []
    for i in top_url_list:
        result = re.findall("\/([a-z]+[0-9][0-9]\W[a-z]+)", str(urlopen(i).read()))
```

Where the objective is to grab all of the instances where the regex checks out, hence the 'findall()" function.  The problem is, it's important that I only get distinct/uniques of each instance.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

[`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) gives *non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings*. You can convert it into unique values using [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-set). Sample example regarding how `set()` works:

```
>>> my_list = [1, 5, 2, 5, 2, 7]
>>> set(my_list)
set([1, 2, 5, 7])  # Duplicate entries of 5 and 2 are removed
```