# How to output only unique gene id's?

Tags: python, fasta, nano

I am working on a project using the following command within `nano`:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import sys
import re 

     fasta_file = (sys.argv[1])
        for myfile in SeqIO.parse(fasta_file, "fasta"):
          if len(myfile) > 250:
           gene_id = myfile.id
           mylist = re.match(r"H149xcV_\w+_\w+_\w+", gene_id)
           print (">"+list.group(0))
```

and its providing with the following outout:

```
    >H149xcV_Fge342_r3_h2_d1
    >H149xcV_bTr423_r3_h2_d1
    >H149xcV_kN893_r3_h2_d1
    >H149xcV_DNp021_r3_h2_d1
    >H149xcV_JEP3324_r3_h2_d1
    >H149xcV_JEP3324_r3_h2_d1
    >H149xcV_JEP3324_r3_h2_d1
    >H149xcV_JEP3324_r3_h2_d1
    >H149xcV_SRt424234_r3_h2_d1
    >H149xcV_SRt424234_r3_h2_d1
    >H149xcV_SRt424234_r3_h2_d1
    >H149xcV_SRt424234_r3_h2_d1
```

How can I change my command so that it provides me with and that are **UNIQUE**:

```
>H149xcV_Fge342_r3_h2
>H149xcV_bTr423_r3_h2
>H149xcV_kN893_r3_h2
>H149xcV_DNp021_r3_h2
>H149xcV_JEP3324_r3_h2
>H149xcV_SRt424234_r3_h2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a capturing group and use that in the replacement.

To prevent unnecessary backtracking, you can exclude the underscore from the word characters using a negated character class `[^\W_]+`

```
(H149xcV_[^\W_]+_[^\W_]+)_[^\W_]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XvGQtM/1)

```
list = re.match(r"(H149xcV_[^\W_]+_[^\W_]+)_[^\W_]+", gene_id)
print (">"+list.group(1))
```

Comment: Hi @Thefourthbird, the output worked! The issue now is that I am obtaining duplicates of the same gene, I tried using `uniq` to obtain only the unique genes but it doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: @AlphaQueUp Add your values to a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set)

Comment: I tried that, but I still kept getting duplicates. I am not sure if I wrote the command properly.

Comment: @AlphaQueUp Also note that you have renamed list to mylist. See an example here https://ideone.com/HimH0B

Comment: Hi @Thefourthbird sorry I am just having trouble integrating into the original command, it still wouldn't work. There are over 20000 gene id's, would I have to manually add my values to a set?

Comment: @AlphaQueUp This demo does not work, but you can try the code in it https://ideone.com/eBcNOP

Answer (score 0):

you can be explicit with classes as `\w+` will match [a-zA-Z0-9_] so even you have multiple `\w+` it doesn't matter.

```
H149xcV_[a-zA-Z0-9]+_[a-zA-Z0-9]+_[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CWFwsD/1)

try to use Regex [Cheatsheet](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html) when developing regex, it helps a lot.

a little clever way:

```
(H149xcV(_[a-zA-z0-9]+){3})

(                   start of group 1
H149xcV             match literal text
(                   start of sub-group 1
_                   match underscore
[a-zA-Z0-9]         word with digits
+                   more than one occurrence
)                   end of sub-group 1
{3}                 should repeat 3 times 
)                   end of group 1
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YQ3aCj/1)

Comment: thats makes sense! thanks! I should have mentioned in the question, but is there a way to only obtain unique genes and not duplicates? I tried using `sort`|`uniq` on the command line but it doesn't seem to be working? @KamranPervaiz

Comment: @AlphaQueUp you can use `re.findall` to get the list and convert your list using `set(mylist)`. take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165530/re-findall-where-i-want-all-unique-instances-of-the-regex-on-the-page

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in part of a regex match, use groups to single that part out:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import sys
import re 

fasta_file = (sys.argv[1])
for myfile in SeqIO.parse(fasta_file, "fasta"):
    if len(myfile) > 250:
        gene_id = myfile.id
        list = re.match(r"(H149xcV_\w+_\w+)_\w+", gene_id)
        print (">"+list.group(1))
```

That should get you the output you need.

You also asked about ensure that there are no duplicates in the output. To do that, you'd need to keep a record of what you already wrote, which means they all end up in memory - if you're doing that anyway, you may as well build the list in memory and write it once complete. This is assuming your dataset isn't so large that it wouldn't fit in memory.

A solution would look like:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import sys
import re 

fasta_file = (sys.argv[1])
# by collecting results in a set, they are guaranteed to be unique
result = set()
for myfile in SeqIO.parse(fasta_file, "fasta"):
    if len(myfile) > 250:
        gene_id = myfile.id
        m = re.match(r"(H149xcV_\w+_\w+)_\w+", gene_id)
        if m.group(1) not in result:
            print(">"+m.group(1))
        result.add(m.group(1))
```

Another approach would be to build `result` and print it once complete, but that has the disadvantage of the result no longer being in the same order as the original, although it would be a little faster (since you no longer have to check if `m.group(1) not in result` for every line).

Comment: Yes I am, thanks very much! @Grismar how could I change it that I only obtain only unique gene id's, right now I am receiving duplicates of the same gene.